# Find the parent yaml node of an array element using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

Assuming I have a `yaml` file more or less like this

```yaml
foo:
 - element1
 - element2
bar: 
 - element3
 - element4
```

What is the `yq` command to get the parent of `element4` (I want to get `bar`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to_entries | .[] | select(.value[] | contains("element4")).key
```

Will loop over the result of `to_entries`, search where `.value` `contains` `element4`, and logs `.key` of the result.